# how do I get email_re from django to work within a python webapp project in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications

When I import it inside a handler with this:

```
from django.core.validators import email_re
```

I get the following error when I run the app:

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/django/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in _import_settings
    raise EnvironmentError, "Environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
EnvironmentError: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

It's unclear to me how to set that environment variable in a webapp project. Do I need to add some additional settings.py file? Any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following lines of code after your imports:

```
from django.conf import settings 
settings.configure()
```

Read here for more info: http://groups.google.com/group/tipfy/browse_thread/thread/78c17b4f82c894a6

Comment: awesome, thank you. for anyone else who runs into this, make sure to put the above lines along with the email_re import at the top in your global imports section and not inside a handler. I first tried putting this inside a handler and got the error that my settings had already been configured.